# How do you add a title attribute to a link generated by rinku auto_link in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is the code currently in auto_html.rb

The title needs to be dynamic, basically a full URL for a truncated URL where the truncated URL is generated by the auto_link.

```
AutoHtml.add_filter(:link).with({}) do |text, options|
  attributes = Array(options).reject { |k,v| v.nil? }.map { |k, v| %{#{k}="#{REXML::Text::normalize(v)}"} }.join(' ')

  Rinku.auto_link(text, :all, attributes) do |url|
      url.gsub(/https?:\/\//, "").truncate(25)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional attributes as part of the string that gets passed into the third argument:

```
Rinku.auto_link(text, :all, 'title="my title" target="_blank"')
```

In your case you could just append it to the attributes variable:

```
AutoHtml.add_filter(:link).with({}) do |text, options|
  attributes = Array(options).reject { |k,v| v.nil? }.map { |k, v| %{#{k}="#{REXML::Text::normalize(v)}"} }.join(' ')

  attributes += ' title="My title"'

  Rinku.auto_link(text, :all, attributes) do |url|
      url.gsub(/https?:\/\//, "").truncate(25)
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I was hoping to put a dynamic title there though.  Basically the full link text for a truncated link so users can see where the link will take them.